# R Get Sum of Data frame Column By Another Column Variable

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

So I need to take the sum of a dataframe with two particulars columns of interest
Col1 : Numeric Data
Col2 : Years

So I need to take the sum of Numeric Data by the years mentioned in the Years Column. 
Then I need to plot the aggregates on y-axis and the years on x-axis.
I tried the following:

`agg <- tapply(Col1, Col2, FUN=sum)`

but I'm unable to get the year names displayed in the x-axis in the plot.
In one of the solutions I found, the following formula was used:

`aggregate(Col1 ~ Col2,Dataframe, FUN=sum)`

Can someone explain how this formula works? 
I understand the use of `~` in plotting, but not in this formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `aggregate()` function the tilde-operator basically tells R to sum the Col1 values by Col2. 
Then to plot you simply do `plot(Col1 ~ Col2, Dataframe)`.

So for an example with simulated data:

```
#data.frame with numeric data and years
d <- data.frame(year = rep(2010:2020, each = 5),
                value = rnorm(55))

#aggregate to calculate sum per year
d2 <- aggregate(value ~ year, d, sum)

#plot the results (as a line graph)
plot(value ~ year, d2, type = 'l')
```

Hope I understood your question correctly and addressed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr solution:

```
library(ggplot2);library(dplyr)
```

**Data**

```
data = tibble(year = c(sample(c(2000:2020), size = 20)), numericData = runif(20, 0, 100))
```

**Aggregate and Make Plot**

```
data %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(aggregated = sum(numericData)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, aggregated)) +
  geom_line()
```

PS: It is always helpful to provide some sample code or data.